# The name of a package conflicts with imported package

Tags: java, scala, package

I have named my package in Scala application as '`org.myname.myproject`'. Here is what I have in one of the source files:

```
package org.myname.myproject

import org.json.JSONObject
import org.myname.myproject.subnamespace.Class123
import scala.Exception
```

And `sbt` says that `object json is not a member of package org`, probably, because of first org in my package name.

What do I do about it? I don't want to rename the package just because I'd like to use `org` as a prefix in all my Scala/Java projects.

UPDATE:

**build.sbt**

```
name := "myproject"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.10.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.json" % "json" % "20090211"
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not because you have no org.json in your classpath?

Comment: I'm with @fge, i think that's the problem.

Comment: @fge, what's classpath? I'm using sbt.

Comment: @MariusKavansky the clashpath is the path where the compiled finds the libraries and the code to be compiled. Even if you use sbt, there is a classpath (and sbt takes care of it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the org.json.JSONObject is not in the main java packages. You should put the class in your **classpath**, using a jar or using directly the source code.